# theme() parameters sent to output.tpl.php

Tags: theming

What I am trying to do, is to set some variables in my function and to send this to my output.tpl.php.

My steps are the following.

1. Declare my theme template

   ```
   function mymodule_theme() {
     return array(
       'my_file' => array('template' => 'output')
     );
   };
   ```
2. Define the following function

   ```
   function mymodule_myfunction() {
     $build['variables'] = array(
       '#theme' => 'my_file', 
       '#variables' => $my_vars
     ); 
     return $build;
   }
   ```
3. I use the following code for my output file (output.tpl.php)

   ```
   <?php echo $my_vars[0]; ?>
   ```

I get an error saying *`$my_vars` is unknown*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That isn't how to use theme functions at all - have you read the docs?

Comment: I can'f find a solution. If it is wrong, show me please what is wrong. My code works, but not $my_vars ouput of my variable.

Comment: Sorry but there's too much wrong there for me to pick it apart in comments/an answer - read the documentation, copy out the examples into a test site so that you know your methods are correct, and _then_ worry about actually trying to implement it. I mean no offence, but it looks a lot like you're guessing rather than basing your code on examples or official documentation

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/933976) for learning how to theme correctly. To add variables to a 'correct' tpl file use [preprocess](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) functions.

Comment: I have read this documentation. I would like to gererate my variables in mymodule_myfunction() and not in template_preprocess_foo(). Can anybody to add existing code to make it workable?

Comment: @clive The OP seems confused about the name of the theme function he implemented. I can at least write an answer about that. I am not sure why the OP wants to use a theme function, but theme functions are normally preferred.

Comment: @user52660 If you've read the documentation, why doesn't your code look anything like the documentation? I'm not having a go, but it's difficult to know how you've gone so far wrong when you've read the documentation. Could you maybe edit the question and quote a couple of the parts that have led you to believe your current code is heading in the right direction? The theme layer is a bit complicated, it's important to know where your misunderstanding is as reproducing the entire docs here isn't going to happen

Comment: Actually, I can answer also the _When is a theme function preferable?_ part. Stay tuned.

Comment: I have renamed my function, it has wrong name. Now is my example understandable. If I call a function mymodule_myfunction() - it has to call and to show the content of output.tpl.php. And it work, but I can not read out my array $my_vars

Comment: If you don't want to use the Drupal functions to do what they are designed to do why use Drupal? If you MUST use your function, add a call to it in the preprocess function and pass it the referenced $vars.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Override template files based on template filename as well as hook name](https://www.drupal.org/node/342350), if you theme function is *my_file*, your template file needs to be *my-file.tpl.php*; you cannot use *output.tpl.php* because Drupal would not recognize it as template file, at least until Drupal code is not changed as per the issue I linked.
The variables that you pass to the template file needs to be defined in your implementation of `hook_theme()`.

Your code should be similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_output' => array('template' => 'mymodule-output', variables => array('my_vars' => NULL))
  );
};

function mymodule_myfunction() {
  // Add here the code that initializes $my_vars.
  // …

  $build['variables'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_output', 
    '#my_vars' => $my_vars
  ); 
  return $build;
}
```

```
// mymodule-output.tpl.php
<?php echo $my_vars[0]; ?>
```

I used mymodule_output as name of the theme function and mymodule-output.tpl.php as name of the template because the coding standards used from Drupal suggests to use the module name as prefix; it would not change if you used *output* where I used *mymodule-output* or *mymodule_output*.

If all you are doing is printing a variable, then you don't need a theme. Theme functions (and template files) are used when you plan to allow themes or other modules to alter the output of your module. That is why Drupal uses *node* as theme function: to allow themes to alter how a node is rendered. The Node module defines its own [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7) file, and the Bartik theme uses its own [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes%21bartik%21templates%21node.tpl.php/7).

Answer (score -1):

To simplify the task use the following code.

```
function mymodule_myfunction() {
  $my_vars = array()
  $my_vars[0] = 'bla bla bla';
  $my_vars[1] = 'some other value';
  return theme('my_file', $my_vars);
}
```

And your theme function will look like

```
function mymodule_theme() {
    return array(
        'my_file' => array(
            'template' => 'output',
            'variables' => array(),
         )
    );

}
```

Now in output.tpl.php you simply print

```
<?php print $variables[0]; ?>
```

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, it doesn't work

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong...

Comment: @Clive I am doing it in many modules, May I know why? I am asking just to learn

Comment: Assuming Drupal 7...variables should be named in `hook_theme`, e.g. `'variables' => array('foo' => NULL)`, passed to a render array like `$build = array('#theme' => 'bar', '#foo' => 'baz');`, and used in the template like `<?php echo $foo; ?>`. I'm not sure why your code would work, but it's not the 'normal' way of doing things

Comment: Actually I see why that might work, if there's a `$variables` variable injected directly into the template by either core or custom code. Much better to use the named property method though, it's easier to tell what's going on

Comment: I have edited the code a little. echo was my mistake. It should have been print instead. Other than that I copy it from a working code. :)

Comment: In some cases if I want to pass let's 20 variables then I think this will become to length to assign each and every variable to null. I use this renderable array only if I pass two or three variables but in my case I am passing the data in array.

Comment: Which is bad @ShabirA. - it breaks caching, and makes your code harder to upgrade. Do a quick search for "drupal theme v render array" and read the top 5 links or so, they explain it better than I could in comments